# ASP Core, creating unique IDs for users

Tags: asp.net-core, security

Alright so I have users in my ASP Core database in MySQL, basically these users are to be linked to physical cards via a QR code imprinted in it, basically other than the generated `Id` by ASP Core I want to also create my own IDs so that whenever the physical card needs to be invalidated or was lost, I can just regenerate the encoded ID in the physical card, currently my format is [32 randomly generated alphanumeric characters].[unix timestamp], my code is like below

```cs
    public static string GenerateSecureUniqueId()
    {
        return $"{GenerateRandomString(32)}.{GenerateDateTimeHash(DateTime.Now)}";
    }

    private const string AlphanumericChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    public static string GenerateRandomString(int length)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int index = Random.Next(AlphanumericChars.Length);
            sb.Append(AlphanumericChars[index]);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }


    private static long ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return ((DateTimeOffset)dateTime).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    }

    public static string GenerateDateTimeHash(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        byte[] dateTimeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ConvertToUnixTimestamp(dateTime));
        return ByteArrayToHexString(dateTimeBytes);
    }
```

Now my question is, is this safe from collisions? Also I want to ask if I can further shorten this so that the QR code will be more printable on the ID. I just want to add that I have around 500K+ users and not only will this ID generator function be used on the Users but also with other tables such as Chats, Metadata and more, so I need it to be safe against collisions.

Comment: What is wrong with `Guid.NewGuid`, why not just use it?

Answer (score 0):

In GenerateRandomString You can add validation of generated Id. Check in database if generated Id exists. If exists, then generate next one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, You can directly use Guid to generate Id instead of generating it by yourself.

From Wikipedia:

> While each generated GUID is not guaranteed to be unique, the total
> number of unique keys (2128 or 3.4×1038) is so large that the
> probability of the same number being generated twice is very small.
> For example, consider the observable universe, which contains about
> 5×1022 stars; every star could then have 6.8×1015 universally unique
> GUIDs

So `Guid.NewGuid` is almost impossible to generate duplicate Id. But if you think `Guid` is too long, You can try to use some libraries to generate shorter Guid like [CSharpVitamins.ShortGuid](https://github.com/csharpvitamins/CSharpVitamins.ShortGuid).